# Need to change the function name in JS, trying to keep it from breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, var

I'm no javascript guru, I'm having to call an external JS file twice in one page. The JS file includes a function. Having this function called twice (once in each JS include) breaks the functionality. So I thought I'd modify the 2nd instance to a different function name. This works to allow the first instance to work correctly but breaks the 2nd one (The one with the function changed).

The function name is address and I'm trying to work just exactly what else needs to be modified in this script to reflect the name change. I fear there are other mentions of "address" that is legitimate and not associated with the function name. I'm at my wits end and am just not sure. Anyone care to look at this JS and help me find which instances of the word address  need to be changed to correctly reflect the one function and var name?

```
/**
 * execute part
 */
$(document).ready(function(){
    address.bindZipcodeFind();
});


var address = {
    bindZipcodeFind: function(){
        $('.zipcode-searcha').click(function(){
            $('.zipcode-search-resulta').text("로딩중...");
            $.get('http://www.nuvonoir.com/postalcode2/zipsearch-action.php',{
                query: $('#dongNamea').val()
            },function(data){
                $('.zipcode-search-resulta').html(data);
                address.bindPutAddress();
            })
        });
    },
    bindPutAddress: function(){
        $('.zipcode-search-resulta a').click(function(){
            $('[id=zipcode1a]').val($(this).parent().parent().find('.postcd1').text());
            $('[id=zipcode2a]').val($(this).parent().parent().find('.postcd2').text());
            $('[id=OrdAddra]').val(address.remove_useless_addr($(this).parent().parent().find('.address').text()));
            address.hideZipcodeFinder();
            $('[name=addr]').focus();
            return false;
        });
    },
    remove_useless_addr: function(address){
        if(address.indexOf('~') != -1){
            address = address.split(' ').slice(0,-1).join(' ');
        }
        return address;
    },
    hideZipcodeFinder: function(){
        $('.zipcode-findera').slideUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why must you load the same file twice? That seems like the real problem...

Comment: How are you in a position where you need to include the same file twice?  Could you handle whatever you need to get done with a function that you just called twice?

Comment: I'm making an ajax call to a korean api database which builds a list of addresses based on a search, from there selecting a result populates a set of address fields. I'm trying to work this out for billing and then the shipping fields as well, thus two sets.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no way to mitigate including code twice, then there's the only option: write that function was called elsewhere:

- global variable
- invisible element with certain id

or even more magic things:

- field in `document` object or document root node (`html/body`)
- location hash (URL part after #)
- cookie/sessionStorage based on document.lastModified (it is equal to page generating time on server) or anything remaining stable within one page load.

Example using global variable:

```
function once() {
   if (window.myOnceFuncIsCalled) return;
   // do the main work
   window.myOnceFuncIsCalled = true;
}
```